# What does a position means in an ethereum Tx?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, nonce

There are 2 fields in the following Ethereum Tx, named **nonce & {position}**. What does position mean?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nonce` is the number of transactions the source account has made so far starting from 0, not from 1, `position` is the number of this transaction (mined) inside the block.

Comment: Just to add, this of course isn't part of the transaction that you submit to the network. It's just the index of the tx in the list of transactions the miner includes in their block.

Comment: well, that's what I said "inside the block", I thought it was clear enough, maybe I should add the word 'mined'